# Laravel Varbox how can I extend the Revision model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Varbox admin panel inside a Laravel project.
The `HasRevisions` trait on my `Article` custom entity and everything works as expected.

However, recently I’ve extended the `revisions` database table to also support soft deleting by adding a `deleted_at` column, but I don’t know how to actually extend the Revision model to support soft deleting.

Can someone please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add softdelete trait inside your model ```use SoftDeletes;``` and don't forget import the class too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most custom developed functionalities inside Varbox, you have the option of overwriting the bindings.

This means that you can swap the `Varbox\Models\Revision` model with your own implementation and Varbox will take care of using your implementation everywhere.

To overwrite the `revision model` binding, go to `config/varbox/bindings.php` and change the value for `revision_model`:

```php
/*
|
| Concrete implementation for the "revision model".
| To extend or replace this functionality, change the value below with your full "revision model" FQN.
|
| Your class will have to (first option is recommended):
| - extend the "Varbox\Models\Revision" class
| - or at least implement the "Varbox\Contracts\RevisionModelContract" interface.
|
| Regardless of the concrete implementation below, you can still use it like:
| - app('revision.model') OR app('\Varbox\Contracts\RevisionModelContract')
| - or you could even use your own class as a direct implementation
|
*/

'revision_model' => \App\YourRevisionModel::class,

// 'revision_model' => \Varbox\Models\Revision::class,
```

Once that's done, you can write your soft deleting behavior inside your model.

The easiest way to conform with the requirements of the `revision model` is to extend your own model with the Varbox one, or at least implement the `Varbox\Contracts\RevisionModelContract`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Varbox\Models\Revision as VarboxRevisionModel;

class YourRevisionModel extends VarboxRevisionModel
{
     use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Here's the documentation part for reference: https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/model-revisions#overwrite-bindings

Also, you might want to learn about overwriting bindings: https://varbox.io/docs/1.x/custom-bindings